# I can't get the average of child group in my RDLC report - Navision 2009

Tags: report, rdlc, navision, ssrs-grouping

I've tried every possible way to use the grouping to find the child group average of unit price

This is my parent Group
[Parent Group in RDLC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Picca.png)

and this is the child group
[Child Group in RDLC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXRqA.png)

Expression for Child Which is Correct
`=FormatNumber(AVG(Fields!UnitPrice.Value), 2)`

Expression for Parent which is I don't know what is wrong
`=Avg(Fields!UniPprice.Value, "table2_Group9")`

Error Message when I'm getting
[Error in Navision while compiling a navision report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lio2v.png)

These are the child unit price which is also average of some same sold items
[Average of Child Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKGNl.png)

Expected result for parent should be average of child items should be 13.74 but if I were to use simple avg function I'd get average of all the item which is wrong..

So Please Help me solve this
Thank You!

I've read and tried many blog with this same error message but that does not solve the problem